# How to change values in character variable in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

**Goal:**
I want to recode the values of a character variable. I need to simplify values which repeat all the time with differents ways, but I can't.

**Problem:**
When I change this values, codes overlap.

**My Data:**

```
> datos[c(1:30),"categorias"]
 [1] 0FICIAL 1ª (OF. VARIOS)           ABOGADOS/AS                       ABOGADOS/AS                      
 [4] ADMINISTRATIVO                    ADMINISTRATIVO                    ADMINISTRATIVO                   
 [7] ADMINISTRATIVO                    ADMINISTRATIVO OFICIAL DE PRIMERA Administrativo. Personal         
[10] Administrativo. Personal          Administrativo/a                  Albañil                          
[13] Albañil Oficial 1ª                Albañil Oficial 1ª                ANIMADOR COMUNITARIO             
[16] ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL           
[19] ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL           
[22] ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL           
[25] ANIMADOR SOCIOCULTURAL            animador turistico                ANIMADOR/A                       
[28] ANIMADOR/A SOCIOCULTURAL          ANIMADOR/A SOCIOCULTURAL          ANIMADOR/A SOCIOCULTURAL         
419 Levels: 0FICIAL 1ª (OF. VARIOS) ABOGADOS/AS ADMINISTRATIVO ... VIGILANTE Y SERENO
```

For example, I need "ANIMADOR/A SOCIOCULTURAL" and "animador turistico" in the same name.
There are many of them.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is not always the word is written good...Sometimes in mayus, sometimes minus, and sometimes with other letters between it. And if I use ```gsub("Albañil","Albañil",datos$categorias)```Only change first word, but not the others...And I need all word that looks like "Albañil" will be written in the same way.

Comment: My experience is that this kind of problem usually just involves a lot of attempts. You may want to consider these functions to make the data more homogenous: `toupper`, `trimws`, `gsub(pattern = 'R/A', replacement = 'R', x = , ignore.case = TRUE)`